# Android Internet permission failing even though it's in the manifest

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I'm sort of new to android development and am running into an issue only when installing my app from the play store. Basically when I try to connect to my api site from the app it fails. Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="1.2" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.jadestripe.retextbook"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true" android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:label="@string/window_title" android:name="com.jadestripe.retextbook.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results" android:name="com.jadestripe.retextbook.SearchResultsActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.jadestripe.retextbook.MainActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.jadestripe.retextbook.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_comparison" android:name="com.jadestripe.retextbook.ComparisonActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.jadestripe.retextbook.SearchResultsActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="com.jadestripe.retextbook.SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm using Lorg.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient to grab a json string from http://api.retextbook.com/search?keyword=test, for example.

**EDIT:** I also should mention it's not asking me to use my internet connection when I install from the play store...

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: How do I do that? I can only repro this on my phone installed from the market...

Comment: "How do I do that?" -- you do that the same way you do it in development: plug in the device and examine LogCat (e.g., LogCat view in Eclipse).

Comment: K, I was trying to solve this from work. I only have the apk with me and my phone. I'll post more when I get home and have a chance to connect to a debugger. I figured I just did something wrong with my manifest.